# Calling MSSQL Stored Procedure using PDO not working

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo, execute

Trying to Call a MSSQL Stored Procedure. 
Procedure is basically this:
USE [DATABASE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[STOREDPROCEDURE] 
(@username varchar(10))
as

SELECT * FROM 'table name' 
where userfield = @username

---

```
PHP Code
$username = 'username';
try {
    $connection = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server={SERVER};Database={DATABASE};Uid={USER};Pwd={PASSWORD}', 'USER', 'PASSWORD');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection Failed :'.$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Please contact the application administrator';
}

$stm = $connection->prepare("CALL STOREDPROCEDURE(?)");
$stm->bindParam(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
$stm->execute();
$results = $stm->fetchAll();
var_dump($results);
```

The output is: array(0) { } 
There is plenty of data in this database.

I know the connection to the database works, when I change the name of the database in the connection it fails.

However, when I change the name of the stored procedure in my (Call ADanE1Username) line, I get no change in the results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you run this code while running SQL Profiler against the target database to ensure the query/procedure is actually firing?

Comment: I have not. I also have not used SQL Profile before. I will look that up and see what comes up.  I was wondering if the procedure was firing since I could change its name in the code and nothing would happen in my results or indicate in the Eclipse Debugger that something was wrong.

Comment: When I run the profiler, I see a SP:Starting EventClass. The Text data reads: exec [sys].sp_sproc_columns_110 N'STOREDPROCEDURE', @odbcver=3. Should I expect the information after exec to be the pathway to the correct stored procedure's database? Again a rookie at this. I don't know what to expect for this value.

Comment: Well, initially that suggests to me that it thinks a stored proc call is on the way. I guess my next question would be whether the user context calling the procedure has proper EXEC permissions to it.

Answer (score 2):

With SQL SERVER you must use

```
$stm = $connection->prepare("EXEC STOREDPROCEDURE(?)");
```

**[EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've tried that, get the same results.